# Windows Batch File - substring variable that contains ampersand gives '... is not recognized as an internal or external command...'

Tags: batch-file

When I receive a parameter to a batch file. I'd like to perform a sub-string on the parameter. However, if the parameter has an ampersand, it treats the string after the ampersand as another command.

Working example:

```
@set var=TomJerry
@echo %var:~3%
```

Failing example:

```
@set var=Tom&Jerry
@echo %var:~4%

'Jerry' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I realize I can escape the ampersand with a ^, but I have no control over the input parameter (%1).

Comment: The issue you need to fix is that your input argument should be doublequoted, i.e. `YourScript.cmd "Tom&Jerry"`. Then you'd obviously use `Set "var=%~1"` and your code would work as expected.

Comment: set var="Tom&Jerry" gives the exact same error.

Comment: I do hope that your comment isn't to me, since it has no relevance whatsoever to the advised code I've provided above! You would send `"Tom&Jerry"` as the argument, _(not `Tom&Jerry`)_. Your script would therefore `Set "var=Tom&Jerry"` because `%~1` would remove the surrounding quotes. Then you'd use `Echo(%var:~4%` and the result would be `Jerry` output to the console!

Comment: Ok... I understand now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
C:\>set "var=Tom&Jerry"

C:\>echo %var:~4%
Jerry

C:\>
```

The trick is to use the preferred syntax `set "var=value"` (note the quotes and their position)

Note:

```
C:\>echo %var%
Tom
Der Befehl "Jerry" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.
```

but:

```
C:\>echo "%var%"
"Tom&Jerry"
```

Answer (score 2):

Working example:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET "_Var=Tom&Jerry"
SET "_Var=%_Var:&=^&%"
echo %_Var%
```

Result:

```
Y:\>echo %_Var%
Tom&Jerry
```

In your case since you want it to be the first argument:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET "_Var=%~1"
SET "_Var=%_Var:&=^&%"
echo %_Var%
```

You need to use Quotes around the variable and value in a `SET` command in order to capture most* special characters.

To `echo` out the Variables holding those characters you must either `echo` them surrounded by Quotes, or substitute the characters with carrots preceding them. (Or a few other work arounds, but those are the quick and simple ones)